# Why is ${\phi}:(Z, +) \to U_n$ surjective?

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $U_{n}$ be the multiplicative group of the $n^\text{th}$ roots of unity; this group is cyclic of order $n$ and is generated by ${\omega} = $$\cos(\frac{2{\pi}}{n}) + i$$\sin(\frac{2{\pi}}{n})$. If we define ${\phi}:(Z, +) \to U_n$ by the equation ${\phi(a)} = {\omega^a}$, show that ${\phi}$ is a homomorphism. Is ${\phi}$ a monomorphism? an epimorphism? an isomorphism?

So, the book that I'm working in explains that the function ${\phi}$ is a homomorphism, which I understand. But, I'd like to know how one can easily show that ${\phi}$ is an epimorphism; that is, how do I show that it is surjective? I can easily find a counterexample in which ${\phi}$ is not one-to-one using the group $U_{4}$, since $1 = {\phi(0)} = {\phi(4)}$. I'd appreciate some help.

Comment: Should your title say surjective instead of not surjective?

Comment: you're right, let me change that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given $z\in U_n$, you know that $z=e^{i2\pi \frac{k}{n}}$ for some $0\leq k< n$. Then, you can choose precisely $k$ to get $w^k=z$, since $w^k=(e^{i\frac{2\pi}{n}})^k=e^{i\frac{2k\pi}{n}}=z$.

Answer (score 1):

Pick an element in $U_n$. Can you think of some canonical way of writing it down? (Hint: You know the generator of the group).